# NestJS - Kafka unhandled exceptions can't be caught

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, nestjs, kafkajs

I've been trying to catch exceptions coming from a kafka microservice but none of the proposed solutions I've found work

The error is coming from here: `server-kafka.js`

```
    async listen(callback) {
        try {
            this.client = this.createClient();
            await this.start(callback);
        }
        catch (err) {
            callback(err);
        }
    }
```

After which is it thrown and unhandled

I've tried exception filters + passing `inheritAppConfig` to the microservice

```
  app.connectMicroservice({
    strategy: kafkaServer,
  }, { inheritAppConfig: true });
```

But this doesn't make exception filter catch any of the errors thrown